# SQL export, MYSQL import, Problems with newline

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I have a very big database in which I stored different events. Now I'm programming a new program and i have to migrate the data from the SQL database to MYSQL database.

Therefore I have to do some modifications to different fields. For example make a date and time field to a datetimefield. Therefore I firstly planned to use a php script, which worked for other smaller datatables. But in the events table I have about 200.000 lines, which causes a timeout at handling with PHP.

So i decided to use a bash script to make it work. I'm still a beginner in bash scripting and i tried this to read the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export IFS=","
filename=events.csv
cat $filename | while read -r id eventkind name oert_dst1 oert_dst2 oert_dst3 eins_dst forces creator createdat editor editat datefromdate datefromtime datetodate datatotime city street oert note referto state owner verband staat verkehr wasser history einsltr;
do echo $id;
done
```

It works as expected and it reads the content of the file.

**BUT:**

In the "note" field there is content which has a newline char into. The result of the script echos:

```
"VKA_ID"
134301
134306
Veranstalter: Stadt Fürstenfeldbruck"
134307
```

The line with "Veranstalter...." is content from the field "note". If i open the csv-file in an editor, there is also the linebreak.

For the export i used the GUI from SQL-Developer and I don't find any functions to avoid this linebreak.

Anyone an idea?

P.S I forgot to say. PHP parses correctly. I read the file into an array and there was also the linebreak, but inside the array field. The newline detection worked there correctly. Its a pity I cant use PHP for that huge file...

Comment: What prevents you from using PHP? You may also use PHP as cli while parsing huge data no max time needed.... you are mostly free from any timeouts problems.

Comment: i dont know what exactly you mean? the first problem is the timeout if my script is running longer. And with the 200.000 datarows it calcs very long... the second problem is that i cant upload the 65MB big csv file...

Comment: You want to transfer data from A to B , right? It does not matter how long it take when using the cli, i got scripts running for many days. (check if you have for some reasons overwritten the value, per default there are no time limit).  You may also read and write by chanks and while doing it your data must also be somewhat modified to be inserted in B, for example the data types for some attribute coming from A are not neccesarly compatible with data type attribute in B. (BTW 65MB is not that very big)

Comment: Right. I have an old program writen in Java and using an old Oracle SQL table. I have to move this to a new writen PHP-program with a MYSQL-table. The PHP-program is still ready and other smaller tables i could transfer. Therefore i used CSV-Export of SQL-Developer. Because the data in the new program is a little different i have to use some modifications like sting-cutting, value-merging... this is done with a php-script which also makes after that a PDO inserting into MYSQL. The CSV-File comes with a POST-Input to the PHP script.

But i dont know how exactly i have to use cli...

Answer (score 0):

> But in the events table I have about 200.000 lines, which causes a timeout at handling with PHP.

You can use PHP, just override the [set-time-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
set_time_limit(20);
```

or with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

This can also be done within a loop to get "just enough time" to each record to process:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    set_time_limit(2);///allows 2 seconds per row
    //process $row
}
```

Comment: Okay, this seems good for the first. Is there also a way to increase the file-size? i know, there is an entry in the php.ini, but i have to use this script on a server in my company. In there im not allowed to change the content of the php.ini. The csv-file has a size of 65MB.

Comment: use ini_set again? or are you saying using ini_set is also not allowed?  Anything in PHP.ini can be set during execution with ini_set

Comment: i tried to use "ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');" in my index.php. but i still cant upload the big file. Smaller ones work.

Comment: operating systems also have settings to prevent large files being posted, not just PHP.  Sorry I cannot be more help on this I think

Comment: thanks anyway! it seems that apache ignores what i write with ini_set. So i'll try it again with php.